# How to dynamically load var files and combine them into one variable using ansible

Tags: variables, dynamic, ansible

I want to dynamically include var files in ansible. Dynamically means, that the user can provide a list as an extra-var, that list will be transformed into an array and defines the files to load. This is possible so far. What makes it hard is the fact that those files shall result in a single object holding the information.

This works and loads all the files in the folder and creates a variable (projects) out of the values specified there:

```
- name: Load project-specific Configuration
  include_vars:
   name: projects
   dir: "{{project_vars_dir}}"
   extensions:
     - yml
```

To reach my goal and give the ability to specify which files to load, I tried the following:

```
- name: Load project-specific Configuration (requested projects only)
  include_vars:
    name: projects
    file: "{{project_vars_dir}}/{{item}}.yml"    
  with_items: "{{projectlist.split(',') | list}}"
```

I can now call my playbook and specify --extra-vars like so: --extra-vars projectlist=projectA,projectB

Loading these files works, but the last file always overwrites the projects variable. How can I combine it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat complex loop so you'll need 2 files and the include_tasks module:

In tasks.yml you put:

```
- include_vars:
    name: file_vars
    file: "{{ item }}"
- set_fact:
    all_vars: "{{ file_vars | combine(all_vars | default({})) }}"
```

In playbook.yml you put:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: tasks.yaml
    loop: "{{projectlist.split(',') | list}}"
```

Ansible is not meant to be used as a programming language so complex loops are  hard to write elegantly. Ideally you should look for built-in modules which handle your use case (which isn't the case here, as far as I know), write your own custom module or look into prepackaged roles written by someone else.